# Using Bash parameter expansion with Required check

Tags: bash, variable-expansion, parameter-expansion

I am trying to strip the string value in the variable and copy to another variable using bash parameter expansion.

```
initialModified=${initial#abc}
```

This give me the value in initialModified after stripping out abc from the beginning of the string in initial variable when I echo initialModified.

However, along with this I would like to add required check

```
initialModified=${initial#abc:?Required parameter}
```

This doesn't work as expected. And throws an error.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to accomplish both things on a single line? Otherwise why not `initialModified=${initial#abc}`, followed by `initialModified=${initialModified:?Required parameter}`?

Comment: Trying to see if I can get both in a single command

Comment: I've tried similar things before, and never had any luck with it. I could be wrong, but AFAIK, `bash` does not allow combining multiple substitution rules in a single expansion.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew "Required" in this context is a special Bash parameter expansion that exits if the parameter to be expanded is null or unset, `${parameter:?word}` (uses the expansion of `word` as the error message), see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Comment: Bash was not designed to do multiple expansions in one command.  Just use the multiple commands and be happy that they work.

Comment: To expand on that, you **cannot** do multiple expansions like this in one command.